# Where to put code shared between concern AND controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I can put shared `controller` code in `ApplicationController` and I can put shared concern code in a `ApplicationConcern` but is there a place where I can put methods that could be shared across both `Controllers` AND `Concerns`?

Comment: If the method is used more than once, I believe best practice is to define it in the concern and then include that concern in controllers where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want a [plain old ruby object](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/rails/building-an-e-commerce-site-with-ajax-and-apis/plain-old-ruby-objects). Rails defines a lot of convenient structure for you, but don't box yourself into it. Create a regular Ruby class, and use it in your controllers, models, and everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the use case. For ex: I prefer to use ApplicationController mainly for rescuing from exceptions or to set constants. The code related to setting current user, his/her preferences is generally kept in concerns. I like to keep my application controller less cluttered and move logic to different concerns.

The plus point of using concern is to DRY up your code. If you don't need code in all of your controllers only a few of them then definitely concerns are the way to go.